# Removing width tag inside table using regex

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I'm doing some html processing before saving the content to the database. When user paste any content which has html tables, I need to remove some tags and attributes.

I'm extracting the table content via `content.match('<table[^>]*>(.*?)</table>')`. In this content, it has width tag as attribute and also inside style tag. `<table width="462" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 348pt;">`.

I want to have that content like `<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">`. I do not want to remove width attribute and tag inside `tr` and `td`. Can anyone suggest a proper regex pattern to do this?

Comment: Do not use regex for that, it is not meant to parse HTML, instead use a HTML parser. With that you can get those tags with e.g. `document.querySelectorAll('table[width]')`

Answer (score 0):

Provided you manage to get the `<table...>` token by itself, the following regex should match all `width` attributes not preceding by a minus:

```
/(?:[^\w-])width\s*(=\s*(["'])[^"']+\2\s*|:\s*[^;]+;)/g
```

You should obviously replace the matched content by a space.

Answer (score 0):

**find:**

```
(<table[^\>]*) width="[^\"]*"
```

**replace with:**

```
\1
```

---

**explanation**

```
(<table          :  find all '<table'...
[^\>]*)          :  until first occurrence of a closing lace brace
 width="[^\"]*"  :  find ' width="' until first occurrence of a quotation mark,
                    select everything, and close it with a quotation mark
```

[regex container preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqlaR.png)

cheers, poli

Comment: While this Regex may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.